# LiPo-management and alarm-clock sharing on same MCU

Tags: microcontroller, battery-charging, lipo

I am working on a wake-up light alarm clock project using a small 3.7V LiPo battery (5V USB charger).

I am considering using a microcontroller to do the alarm clock function rather than a dedicated alarm clock IC as the LED need a PWM to turn on gradually in about 15-30 mins.

Reading [this article](https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1279173) I found that battery management can also be done with a MCU rather than a dedicated IC.

- Can I share the MCU to do both alarm clock and battery management functions? I don't see any reason why not, but as battery management is something subtle I wonder.
- Do you have reference design for LiPo management for a specific MCU that could match my need? In the article they say most MCU suppliers published notes or evaluation designs for that function but can't find such and had no luck yet contacting MCU manufacturers. As LiPo management seem to require extra care in the code I would rather use reference design.

Comment: Using a MCU means you have to do everything from scratch. Study charging curves, handle temperature etc. It doesn't make much sense to integrate it in a MCU instead of using a dedicated IC, unless this is a high volume product where R&D costs are negligible compared to BOM cost.

Comment: LiPo (and Li+ for that matter) chargers are quite complex things and you are very likely to be far better off using a dedicated battery management device.

Comment: Questions seeking pointer to external references are off topic.  Beyond that there is no specificity to what functions you are asking about, so the only responses are the ones you already received cautioning against this.  Having the MCU shut down when the battery is too low is common, but leave the charging to something else.